# Filtering with RadioButton

Tags: javascript

I'm making a mockup website the problem is I'm trying to filter my content using radiobuttons woth each has iets own value (`manga,manwha`) and the content has class tags with different values (`manga,manwha`) now I tried a few things in JavaScript but it only takes away the content when the radiobtn is checked but it need to do the opposite by only showing the contwnt that is checked

The code that a use is the following but with my own things added

```
function filterItems() {
  // Get the selected radio button value
  var selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="checkbox3"]:checked').value;

  // Get all list items
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('#manga, #manwga');

  // Loop through each item and show/hide based on the selected radio button
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.getAttribute('data-type') === selectedValue || selectedValue === 'all') {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal example of the HTML the accompanies your JS?

Comment: <li class="flex2">
<input class="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox-manga" value="manga">
</li>

<li class="flex2">
<input class="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3"  id="checkbox-manwha" value="manwha">
</li>

<li class="flex2">
<input class="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox-manhua" value="manhua">
</li>



<div class="gridlayout" data-type="manga" id="manwha" style="height :100px;" id ="Adventure, Magic, Monsters ">

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that your code is hiding the content corresponding `radioButton`, you just have to make it so it hides all content NOT corresponding to the `radioButton`. To do that, you only have to invert what the `if` is doing from

```
  if (item.getAttribute('data-type') === selectedValue || selectedValue === 'all') {
      item.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

to

```
  if (item.getAttribute('data-type') === selectedValue || selectedValue === 'all') {
      item.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
      item.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to invert the behavior you can change `if block` like this, and also you can to get rid of the `else block`.

you actually don't need this one `var item = items[i];` in the loop  - it's just memory spending.

and a body of the loop will become so:

```
items[i].style.display = 'none';
if (
      items[i].getAttribute('data-type') !== selectedValue 
      && selectedValue !== 'all'
) {
      items[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

also let's use `dataset` attribute correctly - **dataset.type**

```
items[i].style.display = 'none';
if (
      items[i].dataset.type !== selectedValue 
      && selectedValue !== 'all'
) {
      items[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Uhmm there is also a problem that is ony filters one manga and not the rest there are 11 of each

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that collects all the values from the checked inputs and puts them in an array on every change. It then loops over the elements you want to show or hide and checks for each element if the data type value corresponds with one of the values of the checked inputs.

Hide your elements by default and only show them by adding a class.

```js
const contentTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.content-type');
const form = document.querySelector('form');

/**
 * This captures every "change" event that bubbles up.
 * So every input that has a changed value, like when you select or unselect it, will trigger the event listener.
 */
form.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // Get all the values of the checked inputs from the form.
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  
  // Put all the values in an array.
  const activeTypes = [...formData.values()];
  
  // Loop over each content type element
  for (const contentType of contentTypes) {
    const type = contentType.dataset.type;
    
    // If the data-type value is present in the activeTypes array..
    const isActiveType = activeTypes.includes(type);
    
    // Add the class if active, remove it if not.
    contentType.classList.toggle('active', isActiveType);
  }
});
```

```css
.content-type {
  display: none;
}

.content-type.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <span>Manga</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="manga"/>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Manwha</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="manwha"/>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Manhua</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="manhua"/>
  </label>
</form>

<div class="content-type" data-type="manga">
  Manga
</div>

<div class="content-type" data-type="manwha">
  Manga
</div>

<div class="content-type" data-type="manhua">
  Manhua
</div>
```